# How to load a spark streaming model in typical ML model Or loading a trained typical ML model to streaming ML model?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

My job is to test the performance of Streaming ML algorithm now, my idea is to train a streaming ML model online and save the model for offline testing , that is what i had done. But when i start to test the performance i found that the weights and intercept in LinearRegressionModel is all 0,which makes me confuse.
i'll show my code below :

1. this is the code to train a streaming model,save or update the mode while finish trainOn in each batch:

```
    val lr: StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD = new StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD().setInitialWeights(Vectors.zeros(10))
    lr.trainOn(trainingLabeledPointDS)
    val model: LinearRegressionModel = lr.latestModel()
    model.save(ssc.sparkContext,"model path")

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

2. this is the part offline, loading the model from modelPath and i think it was suppose to be some value in weights and intercept but it's all 0 (defualt value):

```
val lrModel: LinearRegressionModel = LinearRegressionModel.load(spark.sparkContext, modelPath)
println(lrModel.weights) // [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
println(lrModel.intercept) // 0.0
```

So, i wanna figure out is there a way to load my streaming model to Offline LinearRegressionModel , Or i can try to train a offline model and use it in my streaming model ?

any comment will be appreciate

Answer (score -1):

i had tried many ways focus on How to load a trained typical ML model to streaming ML model, the idea is to train the offline model and save it. And then, in the streaming application, befor you new the StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD , for example, load your offline model and get the weights(Or coefficient) and intercept, and then put it into your StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD by setter.

but, my job is not finished yet, to train an offline model and use it in streaming context is stupid for my job, because it is still a offline model not a model trained in streaming context, it can not really reflects the performance of streamingMLAlgotrithm.

I need a way to save Streaming ML model, any comment will be appreciate,thank you very much!!!